# Is this fact true or how to make it true?

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n, A$ be positive real numbers and $k$ a positive integer. Is this correct?
If we have $$\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(1+a_i\right)\geq k\ln\left(1+A/k\right),$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^na_i\leq A,$$ then $$n=k,$$ and $$a_i=A/k.$$

If it is not correct, how can I choose the right hand side of the first inequality to make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some examples.  Let's say $k=1$.  The first inequality says 
$\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(1+a_i) \ge \ln(1+A)$, or $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+a_i) \ge 1 + A$, the second says $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \le A$.  As long as
$\prod_{i=1}^n (1+a_i) \ge 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$, there will be some $A$ that makes this true.  But in fact that's always true if all $a_i > 0$, because when you expand out the product the terms on the right side will all appear, together with some other positive terms.

Again, let's say $a_i = t b_i$ and $A = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = t \sum_{i=1}^n b_i $.   Exponentiating the first inequality gives us $$\prod_{i=1}^n (1 + t b_i) \ge \left(1 + (t/k) \sum_{i=1}^n b_i\right)^k$$
As polynomials in $t$, the left side has degree $n$ and the right side has degree $k$.  If $n > k$, for any positive $b_i$ this will always be true if $t$ is large enough.

Comment: Thank you. Now I think I can say this at least: if the two inequalities (in my question) hold then $n>k$.

Comment: Make that $n \ge k$.  With $n=k$, it's true if and only if all $a_i$ are equal and $A = \sum_i a_i$ (see the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)).